# Linked Data vs Linked Open Data

Tags: linked-data

I do know what Linked data means and what Open data means.

However, today I found that there is something called `Linked Open Data`

Is it the same as Linked data or not please?

Comment: Perhaps you can say some more about what you know linked data to be, and why you think that linked open data would be anything other than data which is both open and linked?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In 2006, Tim Berners-Lee defined the four rules of **Linked Data**:

> 1. Use URIs as names for things
> 2. Use HTTP URIs so that people can look up those names.
> 3. When someone looks up a URI, provide useful information, using the standards (RDF*, SPARQL)
> 4. Include links to other URIs. so that they can discover more things.

In 2010, he introduced the 5 star rating system for **Linked Open Data**:

> 1. Available on the web (whatever format) but with an open licence, to be Open Data
> 2. Available as machine-readable structured data (e.g. excel instead of image scan of a table)
> 3. as (2) plus non-proprietary format (e.g. CSV instead of excel)
> 4. All the above plus, Use open standards from W3C (RDF and SPARQL) to identify things, so that people can point at your stuff
> 5. All the above, plus: Link your data to other people’s data to provide context

Both is published on his personal note, [Linked Data - Design Issues](http://www.w3.org/DesignIssues/LinkedData.html), where he also explains:

> Linked Open Data (LOD) is Linked Data which is released under an open licence